# List of files inside a folder (in a specific format) and continue through the subfolders

Tags: batch-file

What I need is a list of files inside a folder and the batch script should continue through all subfolders, preferably as a batch script.

The outpout should be something like FILE; PATH

I did some research so far, and I come close with:

```
for /f "delims=" %a in ('cd') do @for /f %b in ('dir /b /a') do @echo %b; %a
```

The problem with this is, it does not go inside subfolders (recursively) and also it outputs folders as first value, which I don't want. I only want FILE; PATH and not FOLDER; PATH

There is also this little trick:

```
for /r %i in (*) do @echo %i
```

This would be my plan b, it list all the files recursively but not at the output format I want.

So if something like a perfect solution exist, I am all ears :-)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are almost there...

read `HELP FOR` and then try this code

```
 for /r %i in (*) do @echo %~nxi ; %~dpi
```

This special modifiers provide a way to expand the variable for some enhanced functionality. 
`%~dpi` expands `%i` to the drive and path, and `%~nxi` expands to file name and extension